# didSelectRowAt indexPath method called after long pressing the UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I'm developing a simple shopping app. There I used UITableView for listing the product but when I select the listed product in the particular cell, "didSelectRowAt indexPath" method has not been called/triggered, so I tried with long pressing UITableViewCell the method is working good and also triggered properly but I don't need this solution.

In the product listing page, I just used UISegmentedControl in the navigation bar and dynamic prototyped UITableView in the UIView. Even I didn't use any kind of UIGestures in this page.

This question may be duplicated and already asked in Stack Overflow, but there were none of the answers solved my problem. I need to continue working the UITableViewCell without long pressing.

Note: I tried switching off the "Delays Content Touches" in TableView, and I surf through Stack Overflow and web but I couldn't find any solutions.

**Update**

"cellForRowAt indexPath" code are as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCell
    let vendor = array_list_vendor[indexPath.row] as? String
    let orgPrice = array_list_price[indexPath.row] as? Int
    let starDealPrice = array_list_stardealPrice[indexPath.row] as? Int
    let url = array_list_image[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.productTitle.text = array_list_title[indexPath.row] as? String

    if url == "" {
        cell.productImg.image = UIImage(named: "no-img")
    }
    else {
        cell.productImg.image = nil
        ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(urlString: (url), completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
            //cell.productImg.frame.width =
            cell.productImg.image = image!
        })
    }

    if vendor == "amazon" {
        cell.sellerImg.image = UIImage(named: "prodicon-amazon")
    }
    else if vendor == "flipkart" {
        cell.sellerImg.image = UIImage(named: "prodicon-flipkart")
    }
    else {
        cell.sellerImg.image = UIImage(named: "prodicon-amazon")
    }

    cell.starDealImg.image = UIImage(named: "prodicon-stardeal")

    let rupee = "\u{20B9}"

    let text = String(format: "%@ %d", rupee, orgPrice!)
    let linkTextWithColor = String(rupee)

    let range = (text as NSString).range(of: linkTextWithColor!)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.black , range: range)

    //Seller price
    cell.sellerPrice.attributedText = attributedString

    let text1 = String(format: "%@ %d", rupee, starDealPrice!)
    let linkTextWithColor1 = String(rupee)

    let range1 = (text1 as NSString).range(of: linkTextWithColor1!)

    let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text1)
    attributedString1.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 127.0/255.0, green: 63.0/255.0, blue: 152.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) , range: range1)    //Purple color

    //Stardeal price
    cell.starDealPrice.attributedText = attributedString1
    let cashBack = orgPrice! - starDealPrice!
    let text2 = String(format: "Save %@", rupee)
    let linkTextWithColor2 = String(rupee)
    let range2 = (text2 as NSString).range(of: linkTextWithColor2!)
    let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text2)
    attributedString2.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.white , range: range2)

    let text3 = String(format: "%d", cashBack)
    let linkTextWithColor3 = String(cashBack)
    let range3 = (text3 as NSString).range(of: linkTextWithColor3)
    let attributedString3 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:text3)
    attributedString3.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.white , range: range3)    
    //Attributed string with multiple words
    attributedString2.append(attributedString3)

    cell.productCashBack.attributedText = attributedString2

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate for the table view?

Comment: yeah set both delegate and datasource

Comment: Ok. So could you share some code, eg `cellForRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt` ?

Comment: share your code

Comment: I updated the code please check..

Comment: have you added any tap gesture in this controller ??

Comment: no it doesn't have any gestures

Comment: Could you also share your code in `didSelectRowAt `?